# Extracting data from multi-line blocks of text to generate one line each using UNIX tools

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to extract specific parts of a file such as below:

```
name = "Account - UU ",
source = "1-account",
destination = "account-manager12",
other = 111111 

name = "Account - PP,
source = "2-account",
destination = "account-manager1234",
other = 1212

name = "Account - GG ",
source = "3-account",
destination = "account-manager12345",
other = 44444

name = "Account - QQ,
source = "4-account",
destination = "account-manager123456"
other = 23232323
```

my expected output is

```
  name = "Account - UU" | source = "1-account" | destination = "account-manager12"
  name = "Account - PP" | source = "2-account" | destination = "account-manager1234"
  name = "Account - GG" | source = "3-account" | destination = "account-manager12345"
  name = "Account - QQ" | source = "4-account" | destination = "account-manager123456"
```

Is there any way i can achieve the same using grep/awk commands ? I really appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Awk is a full-fledged scripting language. One can _absolutely_ write a script in it that does this. (One could also write such a script in native bash, for that matter, not using `grep`, `awk` or any other commands that aren't built into the shell at all).

Comment: By the way, why don't you want a space between the last `|` and the word `destination`?

Comment: Do those missing quotes in `name` also need fixing?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - yeah space is require.. i have edited now

Comment: We ask that you show your own attempt at a solution.

Comment: You just completely changed the input format thereby invalidating all of the answers you've received so far and wasting our time in trying to help you. Now it looks like you're asking how to parse json which is a completely different question which will have completely different answers. You should put this back to the question you asked, accept an answer to that question, and then ask a new one about parsing json.

Comment: sorry about that.. I am new to this unix script world.. really sorry

Comment: It's not okay to edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you need to do that, ask a new and different question.

Comment: sure.. will do it going forward..Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this running at https://ideone.com/0O8t3U:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob  # enable extended globbing, of which @(one|two|three) is an example

output=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    @(name|source|destination)" = "*)  # "name = " or "source = " or "destination = "
      output+="${line%,} | " ;;        # strip trailing comma before appending to output
    "")                                # matches only an empty line
      printf '%s\n' "${output%' | '}"  # print our output, without the last " | "
      output=""                        # ...then reset that output to empty
      ;;
  esac
done
# finally, print anything that didn't have a blank line after it (last block of input)
[[ $output ]] && printf '%s\n' "${output% | }"
```

Comment: when i gave some actual data , it is throwing the run time error. https://ideone.com/DXvMVS

Comment: @BigD, see a version that works with your _real_ input (as opposed to the input you asked about) at https://ideone.com/3GWIy4. I'm not going to edit the answer, because it's responsive to the question as-asked.

Comment: Thanks..working for me.. is it possible to modify the script with reading from a file instead of reading from stdin ?

Comment: @BigD, put `<file` after the `done`, or `exec <file` up at the very top of the script (well, after the shebang).

Comment: I have tried but its not working.. Hence created another question -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64984062/how-to-recursively-get-the-files-and-data-inside-the-files-in-unix-shell-script

Comment: you can find the modifed code here - https://ideone.com/MKwGpC

Answer (score 2):

If we don't really have to deal with missing quotes and trailing blanks in $1:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F',?\n' -v OFS=' | ' '{print $1, $2, $3}' file
name = "Account - UU " | source = "1-account" | destination = "account-manager12"
name = "Account - PP | source = "2-account" | destination = "account-manager1234"
name = "Account - GG " | source = "3-account" | destination = "account-manager12345"
name = "Account - QQ | source = "4-account" | destination = "account-manager123456"
```

or if we do:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F',?\n' -v OFS=' | ' '{gsub(/^"? *| *"?$/,"\"",$1); print $1, $2, $3}' file
"name = "Account - UU" | source = "1-account" | destination = "account-manager12"
"name = "Account - PP" | source = "2-account" | destination = "account-manager1234"
"name = "Account - GG" | source = "3-account" | destination = "account-manager12345"
"name = "Account - QQ" | source = "4-account" | destination = "account-manager123456"
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" | "
}
/^ +name/{
  if(val){
    print val
    val=""
  }
  found=1
}
found{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$0
}
/^ +other/{
  found=""
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: its not working with input data

Comment: @BigD, with shown samples it worked fine for me. Are you getting any error or any other output? Could you please elaborate more on this one.

Comment: I am not getting anything..only empty results

Comment: @BigD, ok you have real spaces in your file, I have made edits now, could you please check now once and let me know then?

Comment: Looking good now.. but am geting "other" value also getting printed ..

Comment: is there anyway i can stop printing values until destination ?

Comment: @BigD, I would like to request you to please keep the samples which you shown at very first of your post, for new question you could open a new question as suggested by all other respected members too in comments, thank you.

Comment: @BigD, change `other` to `destination` in above solution and it should fly then.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of two Perl one-liners and `paste`:

```
perl -lne 'print for /^\s*((?:name|source|destination)\s*=\s*[^,]*)/' input_file | paste - - - | perl -pe 's/\t/ | /g'
```

The Perl one-liners use these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

The first Perl one-liner prints all groups captured by parenthesis in this regex, which create the output table cells, 1 cell per line:
`/^\s*((?:name|source|destination)\s*=\s*[^,]*)/` : The beginning of the line, followed by 0 or more whitespace, followed by `key = value` pair where the key is specified inside the non-capturing parentheses `(?:PATTERN)`. The `value` is a stretch of 0 or more non-comma characters (`[^,]*`)

The second Perl one-liner replaces all tabs with `|` using `/g` (multiple matches) regex modifier.

`paste - - -` : Join every 3 lines of the input on TAB and print as a single line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: Thanks.. am looking for the unix shell script